# How to cite class notes in a paper?

Tags: citations

In a paper, I have used a very classic method, whose details I found in certain class notes, found googling the name of the method itself.

I would like to cite these class notes (something like "this method has been implemented as explained in [class notes]") , but I have no idea if this is common or if I should find a different (more official) source. 
What should I do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you cannot find the material in a more "official" source, such as a peer-reviewed journal or conference paper, then you should check with the publisher on how to cite the lecture notes directly.

If allowed, the exact way to cite the lecture notes will depend on the citation guidelines where you are submitting. For example, in IEEE citation format, I am aware of a couple of acceptable citation formats for citing lecture content.

1. This IEEE citation example is taken from [here](http://www.ijssst.info/info/IEEE-Citation-StyleGuide.pdf):

> S. Maw. Engg 251. Class Lecture, Topic: “Speed skating.” ICT 224, Faculty of Engineering, University of Calgary, Calgary, Alberta, Oct. 31, 2003.

2. This example is taken from [here](http://www2.ece.gatech.edu/academic/courses/ece4007/ECE4007A/deliverables/proposal/2011spring/IEEE_citations/IEEE%20Citation%20Guidelines2.pdf):

> S. Bhanndahar. ECE 4321. Class Lecture, Topic: “Bluetooth can’t help you.”
>   School of Electrical and Computer Engineering, Georgia Institute of Technology, Atlanta, GA, Jan. 9, 2008.

It is interesting to note that a quick check of the official [IEEE Citation Reference](http://www.ieee.org/documents/ieeecitationref.pdf) **does not mention** the correct format for citing class/lecture notes. So you may need to dig around a bit to find the correct format for wherever it is you are submitting.

Comment: A precise description indeed.